Rtl numbers problem when running flutter web on chrome in samsung phones
The text shows fine on chrome desktop, but the numbers (hh:mm in this case) get wrong direction when running on galaxy phones. Shows 12:20 as 20:12. It appears to be that way only on galaxy phones and iPhones seem to ok showing it. Does anyone know where the problem could be? Is the problem with chrome or the flutter project?
The code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Test'),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('ساعت 12:20', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

Chrome desktop (correct display of the hh:mm):

Samsung Galaxy S8+/S20 Ultra (if using chrome devtools, refresh page after selecting device):

Update:
It's a flutter issue (not fixed yet): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/122153

have you discovered any solution ?

No and I updated @Hanaa
